# Need help parse this table

Tags: java, jsoup

```
public String getTotalInfected() {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<tr class=\"total_row_world odd\" role=\"row\">\r\n" + 
                "<td></td>\r\n" + 
                "<td style=\"text-align:left;\">World</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td class=\"sorting_1\">4,815,439</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>+16,173</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>316,853</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>+333</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>1,863,306</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>2,635,280</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>44,817</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>618</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td>40.6</td>\r\n" + 
                "<td></td>\r\n" + 
                "<td></td>\r\n" + 
                "<td></td>\r\n" + 
                "<td style=\"display:none\" data-continent=\"all\">All</td>\r\n" + 
                "</tr>");
        Elements tr = doc.select("tr");
        System.out.println("tr elements in html: " + tr.size());
        Elements td = tr.select("td");
       System.out.println(td.text());
        return null;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error in website linkage";
    }
}
```

Looking to scrape the numbers from the td tag
For some reason nothing was **scraped**. I'm pretty new to JSoup library and **scraping** table is driving me crazy. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `Jsoup.connect` rather than `Jsoup.parse`? The parameter to `Jsoup.connect` should be a URL, not an HTML string.

Comment: I was being a dumb dumb and forget to change the code. I couldn't get the code working still

Comment: What output are you getting? If you are getting an error, please add a proper `ex.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` statement, otherwise it is not useful. **update the question with your corrected code and your output**.

Comment: I got it fixed after changing the parse and looking at the output.

May I know why use e.printStackTrace(); instead of anything else?

Comment: Because it prints the actual place where the error occurred, and what the exact exception was. Without it, you can't know what happened.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a suggestion to counter the problem where the website's html changes and it breaks the scrape process

Comment: @Fenzox to come back to your original question, your own answer doesn't really fix the problem. Take a look at Arvind's answer which is spot on. Without the `<table>` tag around your document fragment Jsoup is discarding the `<tr>` tags and so `tr.size()` ends up being 0.

Comment: Got it, so for every table, the table is required right?

Comment: @Fenzox - That's correct. You need `<table>...</table>` for every table.

Comment: I'm trying to practice connect now and selecting the tr class, can you look over my tr class selection and comment accordingly? Thanks

Comment: @Fenzox - You need to post a new question. Don't add a new question by editing the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `<table>...</table>`.

## Demo:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JSoupPrj {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<table><tr class=\"total_row_world odd\" role=\"row\">\r\n" + "<td></td>\r\n"
                + "<td style=\"text-align:left;\">World</td>\r\n" + "<td class=\"sorting_1\">4,815,439</td>\r\n"
                + "<td>+16,173</td>\r\n" + "<td>316,853</td>\r\n" + "<td>+333</td>\r\n" + "<td>1,863,306</td>\r\n"
                + "<td>2,635,280</td>\r\n" + "<td>44,817</td>\r\n" + "<td>618</td>\r\n" + "<td>40.6</td>\r\n"
                + "<td></td>\r\n" + "<td></td>\r\n" + "<td></td>\r\n"
                + "<td style=\"display:none\" data-continent=\"all\">All</td>\r\n" + "</tr></table>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements tr = doc.select("tr");
        System.out.println("tr elements in html: " + tr.size());
        Elements td = tr.select("td");
        System.out.println(td.text());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
tr elements in html: 1
World 4,815,439 +16,173 316,853 +333 1,863,306 2,635,280 44,817 618 40.6    All
```